# error: no suitable constructor found for Builder(no arguments) constructor Builder.Builder(Context) is not applicable

Tags: java

I'm working on an app and I managed to get rid of all the bugs except one:

> no suitable constructor found for builder

changing to "Intent"

https://file.io/OqhPX8 -> link to the code

```
private void GameOver()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogueBuilder = new  AlertDialog.Builder().Builder(MainActivity.this);
    alertDialogueBuilder
            .setMessage("Ai Pierdut! Scorul tau este:" +mScor + "Puncte/3")
            .setPositiveButton("JOC NOU",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                        }
                    });
}
```

I expect it to work. I am pretty sure everything else is working. The maximum score should be 3/3 if one question would be wrong it the "GameOver" Screen will appear.

Comment: The external link is a 404. ANd it's better to include code directly in the question.

Comment: Is the question related to JavaScript, or is it just tagged that way because "JavaScript" sounds like "Java"?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to fix the first line, by removing the `()` ?

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogueBuilder = new  AlertDialog.Builder.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```